# Simple D3js code not working

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm running a simple d3js code (the first one from [here](http://www.lessonpaths.com/learn/i/begin-with-d3js/d3js-simplest-examples-of-d3js)). When I run the js code from the script tag in the .html file, it works fine but if I move the js code to a .js file and include that in the .html file, it doesn't work.

This code works:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="viz"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var sampleSVG = d3.select("#viz")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("height", 100);    

    sampleSVG.append("circle")
        .style("stroke", "gray")
        .style("fill", "white")
        .attr("r", 40)
        .attr("cx", 50)
        .attr("cy", 50)
        .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");})
        .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");});

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code doesn't work:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="viz"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var sampleSVG = d3.select("#viz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100);    

sampleSVG.append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("r", 40)
    .attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("cy", 50)
    .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");})
    .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");});
```

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: you need to include or call the d3.js script in app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code is run before the HTML is parsed.

You should try to always wrap your code in a dom content loaded listener.
Then it will be executed after all the html and css is parsed.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // ...
});
```